# Why localstorage values can't be loaded on connectedCallback in Polymer 2?

Tags: javascript, polymer, local-storage, web-component, polymer-2.x

I'm using [app-localstorage-document](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-storage/elements/app-localstorage-document) in my application. I'm trying to get local storage data on `connectedCallback()` but, the values don't load. Previously I used [iron-localstorage](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-localstorage/elements/iron-localstorage), in which I used `on-iron-localstorage-load`event method to load the values when the page is loaded. But I'm not able to find out how to load values using similar method in `app-localstorage-document`.

Below is the instance of code:

```
<app-localstorage-document id="catKey" key="CatValue" data="{{cat}}" storage="window.localstorage"></app-localstorage-document>
    <paper-input value="{{cat}}"></paper-input>
    <p>It is {{cat}}</p>
</template>
<script>
    class MyApp extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-app'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          cat: {
            type: String
          }
        };
      }
      connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
        console.log(this.cat);
      }
</script>
```

If I console the data while the control is in `connectedCallback()`, it prints `undefined`. However, the values can be loaded if I try to load it in some other function.

Answer (score 0):

What about delaying the function call until the values are set using an observer like:

```
<template>
  <app-localstorage-document id="catKey" key="CatValue" data="{{cat}}"
      storage="window.localstorage"></app-localstorage-document>
  <paper-input value="{{cat}}"></paper-input>
  <p>It is {{cat}}</p>
</template>
<script>
class MyApp extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return 'my-app'; }
  static get properties() {
    return {
      cat: {
        type: String,
        observer: 'catChanged',
      },
    };
  }
  catChanged() {
    console.log(this.cat);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What if I want to load data on page load? If I use an observer the code will run every single time the value for a property changes. Which I don't think is a good thing.

Comment: You could try overriding the `ready` method instead of `connectedCallback` (don't forget to call `super.ready()`) to run the code later in the element's lifecycle, but I'm not sure this will fix the issue since I'm not sure when the data will be ready.

Comment: That is the main thing to know, when the data gets ready. I'll try with `ready` method too. :)

Comment: It may not be ideal since the method will be called on change but, what about just using a boolean in the observer method to only run the first time it's called with a value? eg. `if (this.catChangedExecuted) return;` and just set it after first run.